# Nested SpringDataWebSupport in JSON Objects and Collections

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-data

I would like to use SpringDataWebSupport nested in objects and collections. Currently I have a setup like this:

```
@Entity
public class MyDomainObject{
...
}

@RestController
public class MyDomainObjectController{
@DeleteMapping("/myDomainObject/delete")
    public void delete(@RequestParam("id") MyDomainObject object){
    ...
    }
}
```

When I send `DELETE http://myApplication/myDomainObject/delete?id=1` everything works as expected. Now I want to delete multiple objects at the same time. Surely I could send several request but that seemed to introduce a lot of network traffic so I changed my delete methode to

```
public void delete(@RequestParam("ids") List<MyDomainObject> objects){
...
}
```

and tried to send this request: `DELETE http://myApplication/myDomainObject/delete?ids=[1,2,3]`

With this request the Backend threw an exception somewhere in the SpringConversionService

`Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[1,2,3]"`

I think the conversionSerivce wants to convert the whole array into a single number. 
Is there any way, to make my approach work or do you know of a more elegant way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by debugging into Spring. The solution is easy. Just use a comma-separated list instead of a JSON list.

`DELETE http://myApplication/myDomainObject/delete?ids=1,2,3`

works.